# Pagenavi pagination via wp-query in functions.php showing same content for each page

Tags: php, pagination, plugin-wp-pagenavi

I've recently had a lot of help creating an upcoming events list (see here [Showing upcoming events including todays event - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343615/showing-upcoming-events-including-todays-event)), as a result my pagination using `wp_pagenavi()` is broken.

At the moment, when you click on page 2 it just shows the same posts as page one. Although the URL does actually change to page/2 page/3 etc.

I have this in my `functions.php` file:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date("Y-m-d") . "'";
return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post__not_in' => array(4269),
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'post_type' => 'whatson',
        'exclude' => '4269',
        'post_status' => 'future,publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

My loop is then as follows:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
// content
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop.  ?>
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) ); } ?>
```

Doing `print_r ($query);` before removing the filter produced this:

[image]

Comment: Do you do any other queries earlier? Could you var_dump `get_query_var('paged')` just before creating this query and show us what's inside it?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż It says `int(0)` on the first page, `int(2)` on page 2, the url is also changing but it's just showing the content from the first page on all other pages. This worked fine when it was just a standard query on a page but since having to move it to the functions.php and add and date range it's not working correctly.

Comment: Could you `print_r` `$query` variable just after creating it (before removing filter), please?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Ok updated question with a screenshot (open it in a new tab to see full view).

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż image is missing. :(

Comment: @MayeenulIslam The image is there, just right click it and open in a new tab. It's loads of text on a black screen so may look like it's missing in the preview - http://i.stack.imgur.com/2G6aa.png

Comment: @Rob: Is there any chance to get it in text format? It's a lot of text, and searching something in the image isn't the easiest thing to do ;) But I don't see `paged` variable in query_vars in this query. Do you have any filters modyfying query_vars?

Comment: @Rob: Just seen it in Firefox. It's huge code block. Better try `var_dump($query);` for a good looking array view. I hope it will help someone to answer you quickly.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż The only code relating to the query is in the question. Should I paste it in the question?

Comment: @Rob: You can copy the whole var_dumped code and paste 'em into Pastebin within a `<pre>` `</pre>` tag and can highlight the syntax in PHP. I tested and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob: Could you publish this entire debug contents on Pastebin? It really would be helpful to see it.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Ok, I'll have to do that later tonight as the change affects the whole site and they're in the middle of a very busy period.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Ok this is the output in pastebin - http://pastebin.com/ar6qJdx0

Comment: @Rob: It was printed on first page or second?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż The first page, do you need another example of page 2?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, show me another for second page, and it should be all clear then.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Ok thanks, here you go - http://pastebin.com/h06Z3THm

Comment: @Rob: OK. So `paged` argument is set to 0 in both queries. It's a little bit hard to say why. I guess it would be hard to help you without seeing and debugging this code...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Ok thanks for looking, is there any more things I can try and paste to you?

Comment: There are many things, but I'm afraid it could take forever doing it this way. Could you give me access to this site or maybe send me this themes files? Contact me via e-mail (you can find it in my profile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this with:

```
function my_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (is_array($wp_query->query_vars['post_status'])) {

        if (in_array('future',$wp_query->query_vars['post_status'])) {
        // posts today into the future
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) . "'";
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_filter_where' );
```

And:

```
<?php
$wp_query = array(
        'post__not_in' => array(4269),
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'post_type' => 'whatson',
        'exclude' => '4269',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_status' =>array('future','published'));
query_posts($wp_query);
?>

                    <?php 
                    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
                    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                        Content
                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop.
                    }  ?>

                    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code to set paged

```
   if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
    else { $paged = 1; }
```

and code for querry

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page'=>6,'category_name'=>'san-pham', 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

this work fine. You have problems like me